# React JSON passed from parent to child component logs as a string, not a json object or iterable array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

In my react app, I'm currently passing a parent state containing an array of JSON strings to a child component, but when I load the array for use in my child component (this.props.pathway_results), I try to reference the first item within the array (this.props.pathway_results[0]), this doens't work because it is registering of type "String" all of a sudden.

This.props.pathway_results[0] logs as "[", the first character of the string, rather than the first item in the array. How do I get the state to register as an object/array, rather than a string?

Edit: I've tried JSON.parse, and get this error: "Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See {...deleted link so that it passes this subredits rules..}for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.parse(pathway_results[0])`.

Comment: I did, but I get the error: "Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See {...deleted link so that it passes this subredits rules..}for more information."

Comment: can you share a code sandbox? As I understand you are trying to receive data from an API and then the cross-origin error occurs.